# Looking for effiicient way to pull data from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I've been recently working with facebook graph api , when I'm pulling user's recents status messages using https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token=...  all I get is a long list which contains details about the status content, and I want to pull the names of people who liked the status.

The current solution I've been thinking about is using preg match, 
I'd like to know if you guys have any other suggestions,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what path you're using, but you can fetch the list of users who like a particular status update by requesting the `likes` connection on an update.

For example, requesting https://graph.facebook.com/10150710880081168/likes yields something like the following for me:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "276700623", 
      "name": "Vikki Carter"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "1514365200", 
      "name": "Darren Bean"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "539760281", 
      "name": "Ian Sidaway"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150710880081168/likes?format=json&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=539760281"
  }
}
```

You'll need the ID of the status update, but also the `user_status` permission from the logged-in user.

**EDIT:** Iterating over the returned data and assigned users into an array:

```
<?php

$result = $facebook->api('[status_id]/likes');

$names = array();
foreach ($result['data'] as $user) {
    $names[] = $user['name'];
}
```

You should now have an array of names of users who liked the status in question.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself well -
I've already got the list of users who liked the status, now I want to arrange them in an array , is there any other way to do it instead of using preg match  ? Any built-in facebook function ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just iterate over the returned data and assign them into an array yourself. I've updated the answer to show this.